# polynomial time reduction of 2 langauges

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, polynomial-time

If we can reduce a language y to x.

`x ≤P  y`

how do I prove

```
 x(complement) ≤P  y (complement)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of many-one reducibility means that, if you've proven that $X\leq Y$, you get $\overline{X}\leq\overline{Y}$ for free.